# Get the value from the function

Tags: javascript

I want to get `accuracy` value from inside the function and create `if else` statement with the `accuracy`. I don't understand how to get the `accuracy` value inside the function and pass it to outside of the function. This is my code:

```
function initMap(position) {

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
        longitude = position.coords.longitude,
        accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: {
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up JavaScript returns and parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can create a global variable, outside the function. and instead of declaring "accuracy" as a local variable, just use the global variable inside the function like so:

```
var accuracy;

function initMap(position) {

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    accuracy = position.coords.accuracy

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: {
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
    }
}
```

Then "accuracy" will be available to everything within the script. To indicate a global variable, sometimes people will use "g" or "_" (underscore), like so:

```
var _accuracy;
var gAccuracy;
```

Edit: Bad grammar/typo.

Comment: if i put console.log(gaccuracy) outside of the function it will be undefined, can you explain like why is that?

Comment: It will be undefined until you call initMap. Put console.log() after you declare accuracy inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! add a `return accuracy;` at the end of your function. Then, you can set a variable to that value, for example `var random = initMap(position);`. This will set `random` to `accuracy`.

Comment: if i put the var random=initMap(position) outside the function it will says that the position is not defined

Comment: Yeah, position is a variable. Set position to a number or something. Position is just what you input into the function. I put it there just for placeholder.